# Unable to show data in correct format using two way binding

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a page here in which i have got headings and paragraphs and pictures and some other data. I am getting data from backend which also contains an array with different properties that will be bringing data in it. I need to show that data on my page according to the properties. Here is the data that i am getting from backend

```
{
  "result": {
    "slogan": "Majeed",
    "bannerImage": "data:image/png;base64,...",
    "schoolName": "JPSC",
    "schoolTenancyName": "JPSC",
    "logo": null,
    "city": "Harbel",
    "county": "Kakata",
    "district": "Kakata",
    "addressline": "319-Hadi Street, Alhamd COlony, Allama Iqbal Town",
    "profilePageContents": [{
        "id": "355156f4-3499-4883-846d-e41bed8a2765",
        "heading": "Yamaha",
        "paragraph": "Hello Guys this is ahsan nissar and this is my school profile page and you can",
        "image": "data:image/png;base64,...",
        "alignment": "Left"
      },
      {
        "id": "d06ce9a5-94a9-4433-adda-ed7efe93f5b2",
        "heading": "Hello friends",
        "paragraph": "I am Ahsan and this is my school. No one can enter here without permission.",
        "image": "data:image/png;base64,...",
        "alignment": "Left"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now in the page i need to show the `profilePageContents` in a way that i will take `property` into consideration and according this property i will show my picture and paragraph data in the page. If the paragraph is enclosed in `class="paraLeft"` then `alignment=Left` condition will trigger and will show paragraph data. Till now i was able to show data in this way [image]

but i want to show pargrpah in the correct way. You can see in the picture that i am getting all paragraphs which i do not want.
Here is my typeScript Code

```
publicData: GetPublicProfilePage = new GetPublicProfilePage();

active: boolean = false;
saving: boolean = false;

selectedFile: File;
image_size: boolean;
image_format: boolean;

dataa: {
  image: string,
  paragraph: string,
  heading: string
}

imageUrl: string;

data: string[];
align: string[];
para: string;
para2: string;
public base64textString: string;
constructor(
  injector: Injector,
  private router: Router,
  private _profileService: ProfileServiceProxy
) {
  super(injector);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this._profileService.GetPublicProfilePage('JPSC')
    .finally(() => {
      this.saving = false;
    })
    .subscribe((result: GetPublicProfilePage) => {
      this.publicData = result;
      this.data = this.publicData.profilePageContents.map(a => a.paragraph);
      this.align = this.publicData.profilePageContents.map(a => a.alignment);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.align.length; i++) {
        if (this.align[i] === 'Left') {
          for (let j = 0; j < this.data.length; j++) {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName('paraLeft')) {
              this.data[i] = this.para[i];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
}
```

my HTML Code

```
<section>
  <div class="paraLeft">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="imgRight"><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;"></div>
      <p>
        <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span><br>
        <br><br>{{data}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="paraRight">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="imgLeft">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:400px;height:200px;">
      </div>
      <p>
        <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
        <br><br>{{data}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="paraLeft">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="imgRight">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/boss.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:400px;height:200px;">
      </div>
      <p>
        <span align="left" style="float:left; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Information</span>
        <br><br>{{data}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I really need to figure out this thing and if there is a way to solve this using angular class binding or using DOM or anything than please help me.

Comment: Looks like the simplest way would be to replace your three `{{data}}` inserts with each of `{{data[0]}}`, `{{data[1]}}`, and `{{data[2]}}` in your HTML, so you'll get one of the array elements instead of the whole array each time.   (But rather than hardcoding each section separately you should probably convert all of this into a ngFor loop...)

Comment: what is your expected layout? Like the image you show above?

Comment: @DanielBeck that is possible but that is not acceptable because i might be getting like 5 or six contents from backend so i cannot use this way.

Comment: @Chybie the expected layout is `if(alignment =='Left') first paraLeft class will trigger and then this paragraph will be added there "Hello Guys this is ahsan nissar and this is my school profile page and you can"

Comment: @Chybie after that again  `if(alignment =='Left')` second paraRight class will trigger and then this paragraph wil be added there "I am Ahsan and this is my school. No one can enter here without permission."

Comment: Yes, supporting various numbers of results is part of why I suggested converting this to a ngFor loop. (Since this appears to be schoolwork I’m not going to do it for you, but that should be enough to get you started?)

Comment: its not a schoolWork. it is just a part of very big product and i really need help since i am not an expert at angular

Comment: @ahsan, basically, u dun care if it's `if(alignment =='Left')` right? what u need is one left, one right and one left...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below part in your code is not necessary:

```
this.data = this.publicData.profilePageContents.map(a => a.paragraph);
this.align = this.publicData.profilePageContents.map(a => a.alignment);
for (let i....
```

The solution would be:-
1. Use the `even` or `odd` properties of the `*ngFor` loop, you can then know whether to assign the class `paraLeft` or `paraRight`. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf
2. Use flexbox to align left or right

Below is the sample solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-list